# Hillegass: Cocoa Prog 3rd Ed: Ch. 33 on OpenGL: Where's the torus?

Tags: cocoa, macos, opengl

In the opengl section of Hillegass' otherwise fine book, we're given sample code for drawing a 3d object on a view.  Two people at the book's discussion forum at http://techstra.bignerdranch.com/ have reported that the drawing code runs, but fails to draw the object.  I'm getting the same result, and the only discussion I've found resolves to a solution for a fix to the Ubuntu port of OpenGL, not much help to us trying to get this working on the mac.

Seeing how the code successfully changes the bg color, everything's apparently wired up. Maybe the object is written out of the viewport.  Has anyone else tried this code and gotten it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it. Works fine. You can download my project [here](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/assets/Gliss.zip).

Comment: I hadn't linked the widgets correctly -- I shouldn't have skipped the Hillegass chapter on matrices (if there is one).

Is there a quick way to make the sliders "live", so I can update the image before the user lets go of a control?  Guess I need to review the chapters on binding widgets.

Comment: Answer: check the Continuous state on each slider's attributes in IB.